# Q.all for a non promise and promise combination

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, ecmascript-6, q

**What Am I Doing:** I take in an array of svn url and then I perform a checkout operation on all the url.

**Problem:** I am not able to fail the `Q.all` when the called function doesn't return a promise.

**Note:** Using [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) version 2.x

**Source Code:**

```
const SvnSpawn = require("svn-spawn");
const Q = require("q");
const validations = require("./validations.js");
const client = new SvnSpawn();

/**
 * Silently checkout the svn content to the specified folder
 * @param {String} svnUrl - URL for the svn checkout
 * @param {String} destPath - Path to the destination folder
 * @returns {void}
 * @private
 */
function checkout(svnUrl, destPath){
    if(validations.isValidString(svnUrl) && validations.isValidString(destPath)){
        const deferred = Q.defer();

        client.cmd(["export", "--force", "--quiet", svnUrl, destPath], (err) => {
            if(err){
                deferred.reject(err);
            }
            else{
                deferred.resolve();
            }
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
    else{
        return new Error("SVN: svn url or destination path are not valid");
    }
}

/**
 * Checkout all the svn dependencies
 * @param {String[]} svnDependencies - Collection of SVN dependencies
 * @param {String} workingFolder - Path to the working folder
 * @returns {void}
 * @public
 */
function svnCheckout(svnDependencies, workingFolder){
    const deferred = Q.defer();

    Q.all(svnDependencies.map((svnUrl) =>
            checkout(svnUrl, workingFolder)
        ))
        .then((response) => {
            deferred.resolve();
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            deferred.reject(err);
        });

    return deferred.promise;
}

module.exports.checkout = svnCheckout;
```

**How the above code is consumed:**

```
const svn = require("./lib/util/svnOperations");

svn.checkout([
    1,
    "http://<url>",
    "http://<url>"
], "./working")
.then(() => {
    console.log("Done");
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
})
.done();
```

**Expectation:** The above code should result in an error but it exits with `Done`.

Comment: *"I am not able to fail the Q.all when the called function doesn't return a promise."* then... make it return a promise? The other option would be to  have everything within the callback within a promise function and using `throw` instead.

Comment: Why not return a rejected promise? `return Q.reject(new Error("SVN: svn url or destination path are not valid"));`

Comment: Thanks @Aldehir. That solved the problem. I am new to promises and es6. If you put that as an answer I will accept.

Comment: Here's an example: https://github.com/kriskowal/q#using-qfcall And another one: https://github.com/kriskowal/q#the-middle I prefer to have all of the logic inside of a promise method so that if any exception occurs, it will be caught by .catch

Comment: @KevinB what should I put in my else statement? Like this `return deferred.reject(new Error("SVN: svn url or destination path are not valid"));` .... this doesnt work.

Comment: If your continuing to use Q.defer(), yes, otherwise if you switched to `Q.when(function () { if (...) {...} else {...}})` you would simply use `throw new Error(...)` and the rest would stay the same.

Comment: Have not tried the `Q.when` but `return deferred.reject(` doesnt work in my case.

Comment: Oh, no, it would be Q.reject.

Comment: k. Thats what @Aldehir recommended too. Thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your code return a rejected promise on failure instead,

```
return Q.reject(new Error("SVN: svn url or destination path are not valid"));
```